# Starting a new version of an activity in android

Tags: java, android

Currently when i click on my activity, since it is single instance, it will try and load the last instance that was of the activity.

However, what if i want to delete the last saved instance and create a fresh new version of the activity via a button press only? So that it will remain single instance up until that point.

Thanks and if i didn't explain it very well drop me a question asking for more detail!